# Testing dependent variables

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm trying to test whether or not I can simplify a function using Mathematica. At first glance it seems there is a dependency of $w$ on $R_0$, but I'm wondering if Mathematica can help me remove this.
My code is:

```
nu0 = (rho0 - (k^2*mu0)/w^2);
nu1 = (rho1 - (k^2*c66)/w^2 + (k^2*c64^2)/(w^2*c44));

rhohat0 = -I*w*nu0;
rhohat1 = -I*w*nu1;

zeta0 = w*(nu0^.5/mu0^.5);
zeta1 = w*(nu1^.5/c44^.5);

R0 = (rhohat1*zeta0 - rhohat0*zeta1)/(rhohat0*zeta1 + rhohat1*zeta0)
```

where I'm trying to remove the $w$ dependancy in $R_0.$ Are there any commands in Mathematica which could help me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster. Answers will not benefit others.

Answer (score 3):

```
nu0 = (rho0 - (k^2*mu0)/w^2);
nu1 = (rho1 - (k^2*c66)/w^2 + (k^2*c64^2)/(w^2*c44));
rhohat0 = -I*w*nu0;
rhohat1 = -I*w*nu1;
zeta0 = w*(nu0^.5/mu0^.5);
zeta1 = w*(nu1^.5/c44^.5);
R0 = (rhohat1*zeta0 - rhohat0*zeta1)/(rhohat0*zeta1 + rhohat1*zeta0);
```

Using

```
FullSimplify[R0, w > 0]
```

gives

[image: result]

which makes it clear that the dependency on `w` is ***not*** removable.